# Installing Linux on a USB

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb, 15.10

So recently I bought a nice San disk slider 32gb usb so I could install linux on it and use it were ever I go. So I created a Bootable install usb on another usb I plug it in and launch the installer I select my sandisk usb(sdc1) and for the boot loader I select sdc1 then I click install and when it finishes it asks me to reboot so I do BUT it installed grub on my laptop. I finally found out how to uninstall grub so I reformated my usb and tryed it again and the same thing happened! What do I do? I really need this usb!

Comment: You should have selected /dev/sdc for boot loader. sdc1 is a partition, and not quite correct for installing grub.

Comment: Let me try that :D

Comment: You can also install via Virtualbox, import flash usb and Linux image and install on it. After that you can run Linux on USB like a HDD.

Comment: Mikewhatever it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to use the installer on a USB stick, but it is probably not a good idea.

What you want is to use a specific application to make the live USB. If you want to keep your settings etc on the USB, you want to set up persistence.

There are several applications that can do this for you, both for Windows and Ubuntu.

If you have a Ubuntu Live USB stick, it might have "Startup Disk Creator" on it. Use that, and specify some room for "reserved extra space".

If you have trouble with that, you might look at unetbootin, or find something for Windows/OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a small tool which is [Linux Live USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/), within 3 steps and you got your live USB, you also can specify persistent space (currently supports some Ubuntu based distros). However, this tool is only available on Windows.

The GRUB problem you're fighting with is because using default installer will fire install grub procedure on whole disks (so you can get multi-os selection while booting up). Of course it's possible to customize those grub to install only on USB, but it's sophisticated.

Live USB + persistent space maybe the simplest solution to your need.